# Why tkinter-buttons do all disable?

Tags: python, tkinter, lambda

I am following a beginner's Python guide book and I am stuck with one particular task with tkinter. I've followed the code from the book but it still does not seem to work properly:

The purpose is to make a guessing game where buttons are pressed two times. If the user finds two same symbols after guessing two times in a row, those buttons/symbols are disabled and stay visible. In other case, they are hidden and guessing starts again. **Problem is:** After pressing the buttons they all stay visible. Please see attachment. [Screenshot of outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Wo2z.jpg)

For doing this code I am using Jupyter Notebook 5.5.0 which has worked well with other exercises in the book. I was wondering if it is about the notebook (also the graphics look different here than in the book) I am using or just a bug in the code?

Thanks in advance!

```
import random
import time
from tkinter import Tk, Button, DISABLED 

def show_symbol(x, y): 

    global first 
    global previousX, previousY
    buttons[x, y]["text"] = button_symbols[x, y] 
    buttons[x, y].update_idletasks() 

    if first: 

        previousX = x 
        previousY = y
        first = False 

    elif previousX != x or previousY != y: 

        if buttons[previousX, previousY]["text"] != buttons[previousX, previousY]["text"]: 

            time.sleep(0.5) 
            buttons[previousX, previousY]["text"] = ""
            buttons[x, y]["text"] = ""

        else: 

            buttons[previousX, previousY]["command"] = DISABLED
            buttons[x, y]["command"] = DISABLED 

        first = True 

root = Tk()
root.title("Find a pair")
root.geometry("500x500") 
root.resizable(width=False, height=False) 

buttons = {}
first = True
previousX = 0 
previousY = 0 

button_symbols = {}
symbols = [u"\u2702", u"\u2702", u"\u2705", u"\u2705", u"\u2708", u"\u2708", u"\u2709", u"\u2709", u"\u270A", u"\u270A",
          u"\u270B", u"\u270B", u"\u270C", u"\u270C", u"\u270F", u"\u270F", u"\u2712", u"\u2712", u"\u2714", u"\u2714",
          u"\u2716", u"\u2716", u"\u2728", u"\u2728"]

random.shuffle(symbols)

for x in range(6): 

    for y in range(4):

        button = Button(command=lambda x=x, y=y: show_symbol(x, y), width=3, height=3)
        button.grid(column=x, row=y) 
        buttons[x, y] = button 
        button_symbols[x, y] = symbols.pop() 

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I don't understand your description of how to play the game and the problem. Perhaps you should remove the random shuffle so the symbols are always the same and then specify exactly what steps to take to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following if statement will always return false because it is checking if *itself* is not equal to *itself*. A simple oversight ;)

```
if buttons[previousX, previousY]["text"] != buttons[previousX, previousY]["text"]:
```

Just change it to the following:

```
if buttons[previousX, previousY]["text"] != buttons[x, y]["text"]:
```

I tested your code and it works with that change